# Why MySQL doesn't drop associated indexes when a column is dropped?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, alter-table

Consider the following use-case scenario:

Suppose, I've a table named `messages`

**messages**

```
- id 
- account_id
- conversation_id
- msg
- msg_type
- timestamp
```

The indexes in the `messages` table are as follows:

```
- idx_messages_account_id_timestamp (account_id,timestamp)
- idx_messages_account_id_conversation_id (account_id, conversation_id)
```

Now, I need to drop the column `conversation_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE messages DROP COLUMN conversation_id;
```

---

After dropping the `conversation_id` column I checked the indexes and found the same indexes there.

I thought `MySQL` would delete all the associated indexes when a column is dropped.

So, what's the usage of such indexes (e.g. `idx_messages_account_id_conversation_id` ) when the corresponding column is no more existent?

Comment: Yes, the indexes remain, but if you check the `idx_messages_account_id_conversation_id` index, you'll see that it no longer includes the `conversation_id` column.  So the index is not the same as before.

Comment: Think left-most for composites. And a battery of queries that would rely on them. Dropping just a part of that composite (one column) under your theory would force table scans if the key is dropped